# Enqueue is not working in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

New to wordpress so not sure what is going on, but my styles are not being added to the head.

```
<?php
function enqueue_styles() {
wp_register_style('bootstrap',get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
wp_register_style('fontawesome', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css', array('bootstrap'));
wp_register_style('animate', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/animate.min.css');
wp_register_style('openSans', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800');
wp_register_style('weather', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400,300,300italic,400italic,700,700italic,900,900italic');
wp_register_style('style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array('bootstrap'));
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'fontawesome' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'animate' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'openSans' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'weather' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'style' );
echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri();
 // wp_enqueue_style( 'stylesheet', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800');
 // wp_enqueue_style( 'stylesheet', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400,300,300italic,400italic,700,700italic,900,900italic');
 // wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css', array() );
 // wp_enqueue_style( 'stylesheet', get_template_directory_uri() . '/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css');
 // wp_enqueue_style( 'stylesheet', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/animate.min.css');
 // wp_enqueue_style( 'stylesheet', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_styles' );

?>
```

I first tried importing them using css to the main style sheet but that did not work. When I searched online this looked like the best way to do this, but again I have no idea why it is not working.

Comment: Does your theme have `<?php wp_head(); ?>` inside the `<head></head>` portion of the html?

Comment: Have you checked the console log to see if you're getting any errors loading the stylesheets? Where do you have this code, in functions.php or a templete?